# Function inline statement execution in sequence node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, synchronization

I am relatively new to MEAN stack and still in learning phase.

Trying to create a simple application which displays list of search records on frontend along with information on **total count of searched records** and **count of distinct customer names** in the dataset.
I have written a separate function in node.js to return total count and distinct count but I believe due to async nature, response(Code 3 below) is executed before code to count the distinct(Code 2 below) is executed. Due to this value of distinct count is always 0.

Below is my code

```
function xyz(req, res, next)
{
     //Code 1 - Get the data 
     query = Recs.find({ $and: searchQuery });

    //Code 2 - Query to get distict cust name count
    query.find().distinct('custName',function (err, distinct_cust_count) {
        cust_count = distinct_cust_count.length;
    });

    //Code 3 - Response
    if (query == null) res.send({total: 0,c_count:0});
    else query.count(function(err, total) { 
            res.send({total: total,c_count:cust_count}); 
    });    

}
```

Please suggest how I can get **Code 2** to always execute before **Code 3**. I have seen some examples using callbacks but that is using different functions not for code segment within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easy way.

```
function xyz(req, res, next)
{
     //Code 1 - Get the data 
     query = Recs.find({ $and: searchQuery });

    //Code 2 - Query to get distict cust name count
    query.find().distinct('custName',function (err, distinct_cust_count) {
        cust_count = distinct_cust_count.length;

        //Code 3 - Response. This will not be executed until the previous query is completed.
        if (query == null) res.send({total: 0,c_count:0});
        else query.count(function(err, total) { 
            res.send({total: total,c_count:cust_count}); 
        });   
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Works Perfectly !!